# Potentiometer Deadzone noise?

Tags: noise, circuit-design, troubleshooting

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  I have a Wind Vane that uses a 360 degree potentiometer as the sensor. The voltage produced at the arm of the pot is proportional to the wind direction.  The arm of the pot is connected to the ADC of an Arduino where the software takes care of converting the voltage to a wind direction.  All this works great with one exception.  The potentiometer has a small deadzone.  I assumed that when the arm was in contact with the deadzone I would get a 0 reading hence the R2 pull-down resistor but unfortunately it jumps around in the 50 to 100mv range according to the ADC.   I should add that the circuit is part of the wind vane assembly and not my design.

So, my problem is when the arm of the pot is in the deadzone, the ADC is sensing a voltage where none should exist.  I have tried a few things, I added a small capacitor across the arm and ground which seemed to help but not eliminate it.  I also added a buffer amplifier in between the ADC and the pot because but it had no effect rather made it worse. What I can do to eliminate this noise(?).  Could the diodes in the circuit be causing this?[image]

Comment: You should verify that a) in the dead Zone the Pot reads open and 2) when you replace it by an open, the add reads really 0 and its not just the noise you need to live with

Comment: How long are the wires to the sensor and what gauge are they?

Comment: I would add in reference to the above comments, that the ADC does read 0.  As I rotate the vane, i get a reading just shy of 5v all the way to 0 but at some point as i continue to rotate, it starts to jump around and settles back down to just under 5 v. as it should.  I assume the jumping happens as the arm rotates through the deadzone.  The wires are about 2 feet long, 22 guage i believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point as you rotate the pot through 360 degrees, the connection must be  broken (or must momentarily short) as the wiper goes from one end to the other of the element.

When the wiper connection is broken, you have a 1M resistor to ground. 1M is not a low enough impedance to reliably read 0V on an MCU ADC.

If you really want this to work you will have to use a rail-to-rail input and output op-amp as a buffer, and it must have input bias current that is low enough (say < 1nA).

You could also just lower the 1M to something like 10K (better to move it to the other side of R3) but it would adversely affect the linearity of the signal (correctable in software at some smallish loss in resolution).

Deviation from linearity is maximum at ~2/3 of rotation. It's a simple quadratic to do the correction as below (409.6 counts is exactly mid-rotation of the pot, assuming a 10-bit ADC).

```
reading / corrected reading
0   0.0
16  16.2
32  33.0
48  50.2
64  68.0
80  86.2
96  104.8
112 123.9
128 143.4
144 163.3
160 183.5
176 204.1
192 224.9
208 246.0
224 267.2
240 288.6
256 310.0
272 331.6
288 353.1
304 374.5
320 395.9
336 417.1
352 438.2
368 459.0
384 479.6
400 499.9
416 520.0
432 539.7
448 559.1
464 578.1
480 596.7
496 615.0
512 632.9
528 650.4
544 667.5
560 684.2
576 700.5
592 716.4
608 731.9
624 747.1
640 761.9
656 776.3
672 790.3
688 804.0
704 817.4
720 830.4
736 843.1
752 855.4
768 867.5
784 879.2
800 890.6
816 901.8
832 912.6
848 923.2
864 933.6
880 943.6
896 953.5
912 963.1
928 972.4
944 981.5
960 990.4
976 999.1 
992 1007.6
1008 1015.9
1024 1024.0
```

Comment: Ah! You're absolutly right. This makes perfect sense and explains the data I am seeing. Thank you! I assume the low bias current requirement is because of the high impedence of the circuit? I do have an OPA376 on hand which should meet that if I am reading the datasheet correctly - my experience with op-amps goes all the way back to about 4 weeks. If I cant get a buffer to work I will go the route of a 10k res. I'll just need to figure out how to get at the circuit board to remove the 1M.  Thanks again.

Comment: You don't need to remove the 1M. OPA376 should work fine. You should keep a small capacitor (100nF perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the effective output resistance of the Pot is somewhere between 0 and 5K Ohms in the active region, but open circuit in the dead zone.  The 1Meg resistor helps, I would believe that a capacitor helps, but you are still vulnerable to any noise that hits the pot output connection.  You might be able to reduce the 1Meg further, maybe to 100K or even less. At some point, the loading on the pot would get significant, but that could be fixed in the Arduino program if necessary.